# Laravel Routing Regular Expression Constraints - not working as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

**Short Version:**

Why is my regex not working with:

```
->where('user', '^(?!(nova|nova-api)$).*$');
```

but this works:

```
->where('user', '^(?!nova).*$');
```

**Long Version**

I installed Laravel Nova.

Nova registers its routes at the very end (after web.php). This results in a problem because my users have the route domain.com/username.

Now, domain.com/nova is not working, but I moved it to a subdomain nova.domain.com. However, the API is still resulting in a problem.

To solve it, I added these "where" constraints and now everything is working.

```
//web.php
Route::prefix('/{user}')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', 'Profile\ProfileController@index');

    Route::view('/{offer}', 'pages.offering.food.show') 
        ->where(['offer' => '.*'])
        ->where('user', '^(?!nova).*$');
});
```

*But* it leads to the problem that, the regex *does not* matches something like `noval`. (Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/lPVrGM/1))

**My goal** is that only nova or nova-api is *not* matched.

My current regex for this problem looks like [this](https://regex101.com/r/oUeSKs/1/):

```
^(?!(nova|nova-api)$).*$
```

I updated the regex, but for some reason, I get a 404 for the ajax call: `https://nova.mydomain.test/nova-api/cards`

```
//web.php
Route::prefix('/{user}')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', 'Profile\ProfileController@index');

    Route::view('/{offer}', 'pages.offering.food.show')
        ->where([
           'anyfood' => '.*',
           'user' => '^(?!(nova|nova-api)$).*$'
        ]);
});
```

I don't really see why it is not working.

Comment: Did you try clearing route cache? `php artisan route:cache`